# How to give own bot permission to see categories?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

My bot has a Command that creates a Category, and inside it, a Text and Voice channel. On creating the Category I overwrite the permission to let only a certain role to see that category and its channels.

Everything until this works fine. My problem comes when I want my bot to see the text channel, so he can read and interact with messages. My bot doesn't have any extra role aside from the Discord App one.

So far, this are the solutions I tried:

- Set Bot to **Administrator**: This solution works, but want to discart it, since **I don't know if it is recommended to set your bot as Administrator**, and I believed there should be other ways to solve the problem.
- Add Permission to Category, setting my bot role to let him read and write messages, like this:

```
await category.set_permissions(bot_role, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, connect=True)
```

This throws an `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access` error, which I don't understand since I have all permission set in my oauth page (see photo below).
I have also tried to give the same permissions to the text channel, but it throws the same error.

All I really want is my Bot to read messages in that text channel, since he won't respond to any command if the Bot can't see the channel.

[image: This are my bot permission on discord/developers]

Edit:
This is how I created the category and channels:

```
async def prepare_game(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = await guild.create_role(name=role_name)
    category = await guild.create_category('Game')
    await category.set_permissions(role, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, connect=True, speak=True)
    text_channel = await guild.create_text_channel('Board', category=category, sync_permissions=True)
    voice_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel('Room', category=category, sync_permissions=True)
```

Then at the end, I added the `await category.set_permissions(bot_role, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, connect=True)`line, where `bot_role` is my app bot role

Comment: Can you add how you create the channel?

Comment: I updated the question with the command

Comment: I do not have any problems with the code? My bot can see the channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the permission overwrites for `ctx.guild.me` (the bot user itself).

From the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=set_permissions#discord.abc.GuildChannel.set_permissions), `set_permissions` will accept a Role or a Member.

For example:

```py
async def prepare_game(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    role = await guild.create_role(name=role_name)
    category = await guild.create_category('Game')
    await category.set_permissions(role, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, connect=True, speak=True)
    await category.set_permissions(ctx.guild.me, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, speak=True)
    text_channel = await guild.create_text_channel('Board', category=category, sync_permissions=True)
    voice_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel('Room', category=category, sync_permissions=True)
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know `ctx.guild.me` pointed the bot instead of the member triggering the command. Thanks