# Changing Category/Channels Permissions Returns Error "Missing Permissions" - Novus/Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

SOLVED - The categories/channels were set to private which is why they couldn't be changed even with the correct permissions. My solution was to tell the user which ones and to add the role with the permissions manually. I added a message that said they can just give the bot administrator permissions and it will do it for them. Hopefully, this helps anyone who runs into this in the future.

I'm trying to change the permissions of multiple categories and channels using the following code:

```py
role = get(guild.roles, name="Fun")
for channel in guild.channels:
    overwrites = channel.overwrites_for(role)
    overwrites.view_channel = False
    await channel.set_permissions(role, overwrite=overwrites)
```

I get the following error:

```
await channel.set_permissions(role, overwrite=overwrites)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

It will work if I give the bot the administrator permission. However, it won't work if I give the bot every single other permission, the bot is at the top of the roles, and it has every category permission. What am I missing?
I'm using Novus (fork of discord.py so it's pretty much the same thing).

Edit: I've asked people in the discord.py, Novus, and discord developers discord servers and they can't help me either. With the exception of the discord developers server they just didn't answer my question.

Edit 2: I was able to get it working when I manually added the bot's role to the category and enabled view_channel. This won't work, however, because that means the server owner has to manually do this for every category and channel which is really inconvenient.

Comment: HTTP errors are raised directly by Discord API, it simply means your bot doesn't have the proper permission(s) to do the action. Check the server's, category's, and channel's permissions regarding your bot. And the bot's permissive role needs to be higher than the role you're trying to change.

Comment: @Taku it’s only in one server that I’m testing it on and it has every category permission and the role it’s editing is under the bot’s role like I said in the post

Comment: Looks like Maybe you need manage Channel and Manage Permissions in Every (i mean litteraly every Channel) because this same code worked for me

Comment: @GamingwithAkashdeep I was able to get it working when I manually added the bot's role to the category and enabled view_channel. This won't work, however, because that means the server owner has to manually do this for every category and channel which is really inconvenient.

Comment: Double-check to make sure intents is enabled!

Comment: @Derek Yup. Every single one is enabled.

Comment: are you as a user able to edit this? So if you make a new account, set all the permissions (like you did with bot). Can you now change the permissions as you want to?

Comment: I noticed you added a bounty, but my original comment still stands, there's no way anyone can provide you a proper solution different than that. Unless it's a bug with the API (highly unlikely), your bot is missing access/doesn't have enough privilege to edit the "Fun" role in one (or more) of the channels. Your code is correct and is the proper way to achieve your task. The best I can suggest you is to add a `print(channel)` before the `set_permissions()` call to see which channel is causing the issue, then manually check the channel overrides to determine which permission(s) your bot lacks.

Comment: @Taku Understood, thank you. I'll have to give the bot admin permissions then and deal with anyone who is skeptical about adding it because it requires that, or give them an alternate method (manually adding the bot to every category and channel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply how Discord works, if a channel is private and the bot does not have administrator permissions or role that has permissions to view the channel, it is not able to view it.

You can create a new category that the bot can access like this:

```
role = await guild.create_role(name="Fun")
category = await guild.create_category("category_name")
await category.set_permissions(role, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, connect=True, speak=True)
await category.set_permissions(ctx.guild.me, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, speak=True)
```

([How to give own bot permission to see categories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297594/how-to-give-own-bot-permission-to-see-categories))